# How would I check file.exist in vb?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have code to do this in asp:

```
@if (File.Exists(HttpServerUtility.MapPath("/Portfolio/@(Model.FileNumber)/Images/Large_@(Model.FileNumber)_1.jpg")) {}
```

I need to do this same thing, but in vb. It just checks if a file exists on the server. Sorry, I do not know really any asp or vb.

EDIT
Does this look right?

```
Dim imageFile As String = "/portfolio/" & FileNumber.Text & "/images/" & FileNumber.Text & "_1.jpg"

If(File.Exists(imageFile) then
   DrawingLink1.Text = "portfolio/" & FileNumber.Text & "/images/" & FileNumber.Text & "_1.jpg"
End if
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the File.Exists() method in the System.IO namespace.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I added an attempt at this in the original post. Is this the right way to do it?